# How to copy the files from svn to specified location through jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I an trying to use the jenkins to redistribute my files to production system. The source php files are in the svn . How can i copy the svn files to specified folder which build step should i use "executing a shell cmd or executing a windows batch command." i am in linux operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the subversion [export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you will definitely want to use the Execute Shell command dialog. SVN Export will export your files to the production server as mentioned in a previous answer.

You could also let Jenkins check the files out locally using the SVN plugin and then use SCP to copy them to the remote machine.